# Add pagination in custom module by ajax call

Tags: magento2, module, ajax, pagination

I have developed Custom module in which data retrieving from db perfectly, but i want to show first ten data(10 rows) at first page and at second page display next ten data and so on by Ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".pagination a").live('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        page = jQuery(this).html();
        updateTable(page);
    });

function updateTable(pageno){
    jQuery.ajax({
     type:"get", 
     url:'<?php echo $this->getUrl('*/*/filterproduct'); ?>?p='+pageno+', 
     success: function(data) {
         jQuery("#productlist").html(data);
     }
});
}
```

Detailed instructions can be found [here](https://magentopractice.wordpress.com/2015/02/14/ajax-paging-in-magento-for-custom-module/).